# Nifi consuming all available disk space

Tags: apache-nifi

I have some processes that search on a SQL base and play to a queue.

In the queue I have limited the size to 100mb and the amount to 10, but even so the NiFi ignores and allocates everything at once, generating a queue of more than 80GB.

I'm running on a cluster with 4 VMs in VMWare with 8GB Ram and 50GB HD Anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which processors are you using? Be careful to check the Run Schedule for your processors, especially for the "source" processors (the ones that don't have upstream connections and generate data on their own, either from an external source or not). All processors default to run as fast as possible, so if you have something like GenerateFlowFile and you run it with its default settings, it generates thousands of flowfiles almost instantly.

Your source processors should either offer their own incremental nature (such as QueryDatabaseTable which keeps track of the max value its seen, and only fetches new rows when the column has a higher value), or be scheduled to something reasonable (1 second, 1 hour, 7 days, etc.)

Comment: I'm using 'QueryDatabaseTable'.
But now what you said made all the sense.
The goal was an initial setup, my query brought the data all at once, I should have paged the query and increased the processor delay before.